# cups doesn't print any more

Tags: network-printer, cups

I have 4 ubuntu bionic pc's on my intranet, with a multifunction sharp printer, an `MX-2310U`, which always printed perfectly, until a few days ago.

Since some day ago I cannot print any more from any PC, while it seems that from a Windows PC printing is ok (the printer technician who came for assistance told me so).

Apparently, on the PC side the printing job ends well, and the job is sent to the printer. Actually, the printer leaves the stand-by, makes some noise but does not print anything, and after a while it goes back to standby.

`/var/log/cups/error_log` show many lines, but I don't understand if there is any error:

https://pastebin.com/tD8UnfKE

Even if I print through `lpr` nothing is printed.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using a `postscript` driver, while that printer only understands `pcl`. When the printer received a job, it woke up, but didn't print anything because it didn't received the data in a known format.

Installing a `pcl` driver solved the issue.

I had trouble solving it because the sharp web site offers a `postscript` driver for this printer. However, those old printer models only support `postscript` entering a paid key.